# Handling MERGE with duplicates

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I have tables order and intend

```
oano  code  slno  
0001  swg1   1
0001  swg2   2
0001  swg1   3
0001  swg4   4
0001  swg1   5
```

intend

```
intend   oano  code  slno
i/1      0001   swg1  1
i/1      0001   swg1  3
i/1      0001   swg2  2  
i/3      0001   swg4  4
i/3      0001   swg1  5
```

I want to update serial number in intend table based on OA table as above.
The merge statment I used is

```
MERGE INTO ITBG_Intend_ITEMS target
USING (select oano, pcode, slno
           from itbg_order_items
           group by oano, pcode,SLNO
      ) source
ON
(target.icode = source.pcode and target.Oano = source.Oano )
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE
    SET target.slno= source.slno
```

;

showing error :ORA-30926: unable to get a stable set of rows in the source tables

Please help

Answer (score 0):

`Merge` won't work if there are multiple matches in the source table for a record in the target table. Instead you can use `update + join`:

```
UPDATE 
(
SELECT ITBG_Intend_ITEMS.slno as target_slno, itbg_order_items.slno as source_slno
 FROM ITBG_Intend_ITEMS
 INNER JOIN itbg_order_items
 ON ITBG_Intend_ITEMS.icode = itbg_order_items.pcode and ITBG_Intend_ITEMS.Oano = itbg_order_items.Oano
) joined
SET joined.target_slno = joined.source_slno
```

Comment: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended .Cursor  moves to  "From'. Whether there exist From inside update?

Comment: @Vishnu The answer was updated, let me know if there is still any errors.

Comment: Showing error ORA-01779: cannot modify a column which maps to a non key-preserved table. Cursor comes to  joined.target_slno

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that for `oano = 0001` and `code = swg1` you have three values of slno: 1, 3, 5. So Oracle does not know which one to use. If you want min or max value then use `min()` or `max()` in source part and remove `slno` from `group by` clause:

```
  merge into itbg_intend_items tgt
  using (select oano, pcode, min(slno) slno
           from itbg_order_items
           group by oano, pcode) src
  on (tgt.icode = src.pcode and tgt.oano = src.oano)
  when matched then update set tgt.slno= src.slno
```

But if you want to assign all values which appear in source table you have to correlate rows **somehow**. This "somehow" can be done for example by assigning numbers to rows and joining tables this way. Such prepared data can be used as source in your `merge` statement:

```
merge into itbg_intend_items tgt
using (
  select rwd, oano, pcode, slno
    from (select oano, pcode, slno, 
                 row_number() over (partition by oano, pcode order by null) rn 
           from itbg_order_items)
    join (select rowid rwd, oano, icode pcode, 
                 row_number() over (partition by oano, icode order by null) rn 
           from itbg_intend_items)
    using (oano, pcode, rn)) src
on (tgt.icode = src.pcode and tgt.oano = src.oano and tgt.rowid = src.rwd)
when matched then update set tgt.slno= src.slno
```

**<sup>[dbfiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=b01b1de2e9c7eb40022f4b1793619057)</sup>**

Of course there may be some issues like not enough values in source to fill target. Or you may want specific order (in this case change ordering for `row_number()`s). Everything this can be done, but you have to tell us what do you want in such situations.